# Eclipse EE and Swing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I have Eclipse Luna EE but there is no JFrame element.

Where I could get JFrame element? I want to create a desktop(using Swing and AWT) app using databases.

Comment: `JFrame` is part of the Java runtime. There is nothing you need apart from the JDK.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, but when i want to create new JFrame class from menu, it is no WindowBuilder folder in!